# Derived pointer to Base pointer conversion using static_cast, dynamic_cast,or explicit conversion won't call the base function

Tags: c++, oop, dynamic-cast, static-cast

I have the following code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class Base
{
public:
    virtual int f(){cout<<"Base"<<endl;}
};

class Derived:public Base
{
public:
    int f(){cout<<"Derived"<<endl;}
};

int main()
{
    Base b;
    Derived d;

    b.f(); ///base
    ((Base)d).f(); ///base

    cout<<"----------------"<<endl;

    Base *b1 = new Base;
    Base *b2 = new Derived;
    Derived *d1 = new Derived;

    b1->f(); ///base
    ((Base*)d1)->f(); ///derived
    ((Base*)b2)->f(); ///derived
    static_cast<Base*>(d1);
    d1->f();///derived
    static_cast<Base*>(b2);
    b2->f();///derived

    cout<<"----------------"<<endl;

    Base *b5 = dynamic_cast<Base*>(b2);
    Base *b6 = dynamic_cast<Base*>(d1);
    if(b5)
        b5->f(); ///derived
    if(b6)
        b6->f(); ///derived


    return 0;
}
```

I want to ask why the derived *d1 OR *b2 pointers when converted to a base using explicit cast (Base*), static cast (static_cast(d1)) or dynamic cast (dynamic_cast(d1)) won't call the f() function of the base class after the conversion. It seems to call the f() function from the derived class every single time.

Also, strangely when I declare the objects this way. The conversion works and calls the base function.

```
Base b;
    Derived d;

    b.f(); ///base
    ((Base)d).f(); ///base
```

Now, I understood that the right way to access the f() from Base class would be `d->Base::f()`, but why should I use dynamic_cast or static_cast since they won't convert the derived pointer to base and call the right function. I would need a detailed explanation if possible. Thanks!

Comment: `dynamic_cast` is used for casting base to derived, which might fail. Derived to base always works, and needs no casts.

Comment: Thanks Bo, I appreciate your explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately, for both you and my keyboard, the explanation is trivial:

`((Base)d)` *slices* the object `d` to a value-copied `Base` instance.

`((Base*)d1)->f()` will still call the derived method since `Base` and therefore `Derived` are polymorphic types, and although `((Base*)d1)` is a `Base*` pointer, it is pointing to a `Derived` object. Ditto for `static_cast` and `dynamic_cast`.

Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing